# What is the difference between typeof and instanceof and when should one be used vs. the other?

Tags: javascript, instanceof, typeof

In my particular case:

```
callback instanceof Function
```

or

```
typeof callback == "function"
```

does it even matter, what's the difference?

**Additional Resource:**

JavaScript-Garden [typeof](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#types.typeof) vs [instanceof](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#types.instanceof)

Comment: I found my [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23317160/1815624) as a easy to use solution

Comment: There is another way to check type using `Object.prototype.toString` http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object.prototype.tostring]

Comment: just use `.constructor` property instead.

Comment: If you wonder about **performance**, see my [answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32272154/797243). *typeof* is faster where both are applicable (namely objects).

Answer (score 700, accepted):

#### Use `instanceof` for custom types:

```
var ClassFirst = function () {};
var ClassSecond = function () {};
var instance = new ClassFirst();
typeof instance; // object
typeof instance == 'ClassFirst'; // false
instance instanceof Object; // true
instance instanceof ClassFirst; // true
instance instanceof ClassSecond; // false
```

#### Use `typeof` for simple built in types:

```
'example string' instanceof String; // false
typeof 'example string' == 'string'; // true

'example string' instanceof Object; // false
typeof 'example string' == 'object'; // false

true instanceof Boolean; // false
typeof true == 'boolean'; // true

99.99 instanceof Number; // false
typeof 99.99 == 'number'; // true

function() {} instanceof Function; // true
typeof function() {} == 'function'; // true
```

#### Use `instanceof` for complex built in types:

```
/regularexpression/ instanceof RegExp; // true
typeof /regularexpression/; // object

[] instanceof Array; // true
typeof []; //object

{} instanceof Object; // true
typeof {}; // object
```

And the last one is a little bit tricky:

```
typeof null; // object
```

Comment: This answer makes it clear why instaceof should **not** be used for primitive types. It's pretty obvious you don't have an option when it comes to custom types, as well as the benefit for 'object' types. But what makes functions lumped in with "simple built-in types"? I find it odd how a function behaves like an object, yet it's type is 'function' making the use of 'typeof' feasible. Why would you discourage instanceof for it, though?

Comment: I'm not sure if there is an adequate answer @Assimilater. Fact is that `typeof` is consistent to tell you whether something is a function or not. However, I can't think of any examples where `instanceof` would give you the wrong answer.

Comment: @Assimilater you could use instanceof with functions as well however I consider these 3 rules being very simple to remember and yes,  functions are an exception:)

Comment: another tricky part -> 'example string' instanceof String; // false but new String('example string') instanceof String; //true

Comment: @Luke generally a bad idea to use "new String" like this. that creates a "string object" rather than a string primitive. see section here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String

Comment: `Use instanceof for complex built in types` - this is still prone to error. Better to use ES5 `Array.isArray()` et al. or the recommended shims.

Comment: You're mostly right, but for example string can be created at at least two ways:
```const a = 'string';
const b = new String('string');```

Checking if `b instanceof` String will yield true

typeof will work string literal, instanceof if created with constructor

Comment: I'm still confused. Why is `'example string' instanceof String` false? How is it not an instance of a string?

Comment: Never mind. This sentence says it all: "instanceof of returns true if an object is created from a given constructor and false otherwise." - https://levelup.gitconnected.com/comparing-the-javascript-typeof-and-instanceof-operators-8844f23633a

Comment: @DavidKlempfner this is because a string created this way: 'example string' is not an object of type String but a primitive value that is string. If you would want to created the string object then you have to use `new String('example string')` explicitly (however don't do it ever).

Answer (score 124):

Both are similar in functionality because they both return type information, however I personally prefer `instanceof` because it's comparing actual types rather than strings.  Type comparison is less prone to human error, and it's technically faster since it's comparing pointers in memory rather than doing whole string comparisons.

Comment: On other hand, I think it would have weird problems in multi-window (iframe anyone) setups.

Comment: In that case you'd have to deal with proper namespacing and domains.

Comment: there are some situations where instanceof will not work as expected and typeof works well ... https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/Instanceof_Operator#Description

Comment: instanceof works with objects in the same window. If you use iframe/frame or popup-windows each (i)frame/window have their own "function" object and instanceof will fail if you try to compare an object from another (i)frame/window. typeof will work in all cases since it returns the string "function".

Comment: http://jsperf.com/typeof-function-vs-instanceof/3  I tried on Chrome and FF3.X, "typeof" approach is faster.

Comment: This is just false. They are not identical. They do not both work in all of the same situations, especially across different JavaScript VMs and browsers.

Comment: I meant their functionality is similar in that they both return type information, but one returns it as an type definition and the other returns a string.

Comment: Your answer says "both are essentially identical in terms of functionality." Respectfully, this is patently false. As outlined and explained in my answer, neither option works in every situation—especially across browsers. The better approach is to use both with an || operator.

Comment: The original question mentioned nothing about browsers; who knows, maybe the OP is writing script in Node.

Comment: @soviut—if you include ECMAScript implementations in general, then their similarity is even more marginal. They are very different tests. If the intention is to determine is something is a callable native function, I would use `typeof` every time.

Comment: Many implementations of JS (I know that V8 does, not sure about other implementations) have `typeof something === "type"` special cased, so there is no real string comparison.

Comment: Not quite. The `instanceof` operator travels up the prototype chain, looking for the constructor's prototype [http://mdn.io/instanceof]. So, it allows for checking if something's an instance of a "subclass."

Comment: This answer is incorrect, see the answer I added, when an object is created like this: `Object.create(Function)`, your code will break, if you use `instanceof` instead of `typeof`.

Comment: @some is right that you need a rationale.  The framing issue mentioned here is one.  Another is that you can break `instanceof` by messing with the `contructor` property.  See the 2ality post "[What object is not an instance of Object?](http://2ality.com/2012/08/instanceof-object.html)"  And because javascript turns us into [gelatinous goo](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=13942674), we do things like that.

Answer (score 112):

A good reason to use typeof is if the variable may be undefined.

```
alert(typeof undefinedVariable); // alerts the string "undefined"
alert(undefinedVariable instanceof Object); // throws an exception
```

A good reason to use instanceof is if the variable may be null.

```
var myNullVar = null;
alert(typeof myNullVar ); // alerts the string "object"
alert(myNullVar  instanceof Object); // alerts "false"
```

So really in my opinion it would depend on what type of possible data you are checking.

Comment: +1 also note that `instanceof` cannot compare to primitive types, typeof can.

Comment: In Chrome 29.0.1541.0 dev `undefined instanceof Object` returns false, and doesn't throw an exception. I don't know how recent that change is, but it makes `instanceof` more appealing.

Comment: `undefined instanceof Object` doesn't throw an exception because, eh, `undefined` is defined. The constant exists in the namespace. When a variable does not exist (due to typo for instance), instanceof will throw an exception. Using typeof on an non-existing variable yields 'undefined' on the other hand.

Answer (score 54):

To make things clear, you need to know two facts:

1. The **instanceof** operator tests whether the **prototype property** of a **constructor** appears anywhere in the **prototypes chain** of an object. In most cases this mean that the object was **created** by using this constructor or on of its descendant. But also prototype may be set explicitly by `Object.setPrototypeOf()` method (ECMAScript 2015) or by the `__proto__` property (old browsers, deprecated). Changing the prototype of an object is not recommended though, because of performance issues.

Thus instanceof is applicable only to objects. In most cases you aren't using constructors to create strings or numbers. You can. But you almost never do.

Also instanceof can't check, exactly which constructor was used to create the object, but will return true, even if object is derived from class which being checked. In most cases this is the desired behavior, but sometimes it's not. So you need to keep that mind.

Another problem is that different scopes have different execution environments. This means that they have different built-ins (different global object, different constructors, etc.). This may result in unexpected results.

For example, `[] instanceof window.frames[0].Array` will return `false`, because `Array.prototype !== window.frames[0].Array` and arrays inherit from the former.
Also, it cannot be used on undefined value, because it don't have a prototype.

2. The **typeof** operator tests whether value belong to **one of six basic types**: "**number**", "**string**", "**boolean**", "**object**", "**function**" or "**undefined**". Where the string "object" belong all objects (except functions, which are objects, but have its own value in typeof operator), and also "null" value and arrays (for "null" it's a bug, but this bug is so old, so it's become a standard). It doesn't rely on constructors and can be used even if value is undefined. But it's doesn't give any details about objects. So if you needed it, go to instanceof.

Now let's talk about one tricky thing. What if you use constructor to create a primitive type?

```
let num = new Number(5);
console.log(num instanceof Number); // print true
console.log(typeof num); // print object
num++; //num is object right now but still can be handled as number
//and after that:
console.log(num instanceof Number); // print false
console.log(typeof num); // print number
```

Seems like magic. But it is not. It's so-called boxing (wrapping primitive value by object) and unboxing (extracting wrapped primitive value from object). Such kind of code seems to be "a bit" fragile. Of course you can just avoid creating primitive type with constructors. But there is another possible situation, when boxing may hit you. When you use Function.call() or Function.apply() on a primitive type.

```
function test(){
  console.log(typeof this);
} 
test.apply(5);
```

To avoiding this you can use strict mode:

```
function test(){
  'use strict';
  console.log(typeof this);
} 
test.apply(5);
```

**upd:**
Since ECMAScript 2015, there is one more type called Symbol, which has its own typeof == **"symbol"**.

```
console.log(typeof Symbol());
// expected output: "symbol"
```

You can read about it on MDN: ([Symbol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol), [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)).

Comment: `if an object is created by a given constructor`

This is incorrect. 
`o instanceof C` will return true if o inherits from C.prototype. You have mentioned something about this later in your answer but it is not very clear.

Comment: incorrect...from the book : " https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS"  a instanceof Foo; // true
The instanceof operator takes a plain object as its left-hand operand and a function as its right-hand operand. The question instanceof answers is: in the entire [[Prototype]] chain of a, does the object arbitrarily pointed to by Foo.prototype ever appear?

Comment: I've edit the answer, to be more correct. Thank for your comments.

Comment: Also, explanation of boxing/unboxing issue was added.

Answer (score 17):

I've discovered some really interesting (read as "horrible") behavior in Safari 5 and Internet Explorer 9. I was using this with great success in Chrome and Firefox.

```
if (typeof this === 'string') {
    doStuffWith(this);
}
```

Then I test in IE9, and it doesn't work at all. Big surprise. But in Safari, it's intermittent! So I start debugging, and I find that Internet Explorer is *always* returning `false`. But the weirdest thing is that Safari seems to be doing some kind of optimization in its JavaScript VM where it is `true` the *first* time, but `false` ***every time you hit reload!***

My brain almost exploded.

So now I've settled on this:

```
if (this instanceof String || typeof this === 'string')
    doStuffWith(this.toString());
}
```

And now everything works great. Note that you can call `"a string".toString()` and it just returns a copy of the string, i.e.

```
"a string".toString() === new String("a string").toString(); // true
```

So I'll be using both from now on.

Answer (score 9):

`instanceof` also works when `callback` is a subtype of `Function`, I think

Answer (score 9):

Other Significant practical differences:

```
// Boolean

var str3 = true ;

alert(str3);

alert(str3 instanceof Boolean);  // false: expect true  

alert(typeof str3 == "boolean" ); // true

// Number

var str4 = 100 ;

alert(str4);

alert(str4 instanceof Number);  // false: expect true   

alert(typeof str4 == "number" ); // true
```

Answer (score 8):

**typeof**: Per the MDN docmentation, typeof is a unary operator that returns a string indicating the type of the unevaluated operand.

In the case of string primitaves and string objects, typeof returns the following:

```
const a = "I'm a string primitive";
const b = new String("I'm a String Object");

typeof a; --> returns 'string'
typeof b; --> returns 'object'
```

**instanceof**: is a binary operator, accepting an object and a constructor. **It returns a boolean indicating whether or not the object has the given constructor in its prototype chain**.

When applied to the string instances above, and compared to String, it behaves as follows:

```
const a = "I'm a string primitive";
const b = new String("I'm a String Object");

a instanceof String; --> returns false
b instanceof String; --> returns true
```

Reference: https://bambielli.com/til/2017-06-18-typeof-vs-instanceof/

Answer (score 6):

After reading this thread, I came out with a self conclusion and created  a quick reference chart, tested in Chrome.

**Preferred cells (in bold) can be picked up, involving a simpler usecase.**

| TYPES | self | typeof | instanceof | constructor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| null | **null** | object |  |  |
| undefined | **undefined** | undefined |  |  |
| array [] | **Array.isArray([])** | object |  | Array |
| bool |  | **boolean** |  | Boolean |
| number |  | **number** |  | Number |
| string |  | **string** |  | String |
| symbol |  | **symbol** |  | Symbol |
| function |  | **function** | Function | Function |
| class |  | function | Function | Function |
| object {} |  | object | **Object** | Object |
| RegExp /abc/ |  | object | **RegExp** | RegExp |
| new Array() |  | object | **Array** | Array |
| new Boolean() |  | object | **Boolean** | Boolean |
| new Number() |  | object | **Number** | Number |
| new String() |  | object | **String** | String |
| new myFunction() |  | object | **myFunction** | myFunction |
| new myClass() |  | object | **myClass** | myClass |

#### Thumb Rule:

- For checking primitive types use `typeof`
- **Null** can be checked as `myvar === null`
- **Undefined** can be checked as `myvar === undefined`
- **Array** can be checked using `Array.isArray([])`
- **Object** can be check using `myvar instanceof Object`
- **Constructor** column can be utilized in a similar fashion as `({}).constructor` or `([]).constructor`

> I admit, the guide is not fully correct, as Creating objects or classes in a different way can result in unexpected output. For example, objects or functions created using `Object.create()` method, which are already explained in the thread by most of the clever folks

Answer (score 5):

`instanceof` in Javascript can be flaky - I believe major frameworks try to avoid its use. Different windows is one of the ways in which it can break - I believe class hierarchies can confuse it as well.

There are better ways for testing whether an object is a certain built-in type (which is usually what you want). Create utility functions and use them:

```
function isFunction(obj) {
  return typeof(obj) == "function";
}
function isArray(obj) {
  return typeof(obj) == "object" 
      && typeof(obj.length) == "number" 
      && isFunction(obj.push);
}
```

And so on.

Comment: In case you didn't know: typeof don't need parenthesis since it is a keyword and not a function. And IMHO you should use === instead of ==.

Comment: @some You are right about typeof but in this case there is no need for ===, it is only needed when the value being compared could equal without having the same type.  Here, it can't.

Comment: @some does typeof ever return something other than a string?

Comment: So isArray would be wrong for, say, a stack object with a push method and a numeric length attribute. Under what circumstances would (instanceof Array) be wrong?

Comment: @ChrisNoe The problem arises with objects shared between multiple frames: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/comp.lang.javascript/XTWYCOwC96I/70rNoQ3L-xoJ

Comment: You should be using the EcmaScript 5 [Array.isArray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) function instead of trying to create your own.

Answer (score 4):

When checking for a function, one must always use `typeof`.

Here's the difference:

```
var f = Object.create(Function);

console.log(f instanceof Function); //=> true
console.log(typeof f === 'function'); //=> false

f(); // throws TypeError: f is not a function
```

This is why one must never use `instanceof` to check for a function.

Comment: I can argue that it is `typeof` that is wrong -- `f` is all of the following: an `Object` (an object) and a `Function` (a function). Except for me it makes more sense to use `instanceof` because knowing that it is a function I know it is an object as well, since all functions are objects in ECMAScript. The converse is not true -- knowing from `typeof` that `f` is indeed an `object` I have no idea that it is also a function.

Comment: @amn For me, it's a *broken* instance of Function. It gets attributes like `length`, `name` and `call` from Function, but all of them are defunct. What's worse, it can't be called and the `TypeError` says it: `f is not a function`.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using prototype's `callback.isFunction()`.

They've figured out the difference and you can count on their reason.

I guess other JS frameworks have such things, too.

`instanceOf` wouldn't work on functions defined in other windows, I believe.
Their Function is different than your `window.Function`.

Answer (score 3):

`instanceof` will not work for primitives eg `"foo" instanceof String` will return `false` whereas `typeof "foo" == "string"` will return `true`.

On the other hand `typeof` will probably not do what you want when it comes to custom objects (or classes, whatever you want to call them). For example:

```
function Dog() {}
var obj = new Dog;
typeof obj == 'Dog' // false, typeof obj is actually "object"
obj instanceof Dog  // true, what we want in this case
```

It just so happens that functions are both 'function' primitives and instances of 'Function', which is a bit of an oddity given that it doesn't work like that for other primitive types eg.

```
(typeof function(){} == 'function') == (function(){} instanceof Function)
```

but

```
(typeof 'foo' == 'string') != ('foo' instanceof String)
```

Answer (score 3):

**Performance**

`typeof` is faster than `instanceof` in situations where both are applicable.

Depending on your engine, the performance difference in favor of `typeof` could be around **20%**. (*Your mileage may vary*)

Here is a benchmark testing for `Array`:

```
var subject = new Array();
var iterations = 10000000;

var goBenchmark = function(callback, iterations) {
    var start = Date.now();
    for (i=0; i < iterations; i++) { var foo = callback(); }
    var end = Date.now();
    var seconds = parseFloat((end-start)/1000).toFixed(2);
    console.log(callback.name+" took: "+ seconds +" seconds.");
    return seconds;
}

// Testing instanceof
var iot = goBenchmark(function instanceofTest(){
     (subject instanceof Array);
}, iterations);

// Testing typeof
var tot = goBenchmark(function typeofTest(){
     (typeof subject == "object");
}, iterations);

var r = new Array(iot,tot).sort();
console.log("Performance ratio is: "+ parseFloat(r[1]/r[0]).toFixed(3));
```

Result

```
instanceofTest took: 9.98 seconds.
typeofTest took: 8.33 seconds.
Performance ratio is: 1.198
```

Comment: typeof subject == "array" should return false. typeof subject is "object".

Comment: how come typeof is faster? is Javascript interning the literal strings?

Comment: The reason is: `instanceof` _always_ follows object's prototype chain, so performance penalty will depend on how far in prototype chain is the class, `instanceof` is tested against. So for short inheritance chain the penalty will be lower (like, `[] instanceof Array`, `{} instanceof Object`), and for long - bigger. So, if both `obj instanceof SomeClass` and `typeof obj !== 'string'` means the same from the perspective of some your hypothetical code (f.e. if you just making a test in `if`, and not `switch`-ing through multiple classes etc.), then you'd better pick second one, performance-wise,

Answer (score 3):

This is just complementary knowledge to all the other explanations here - I am *not* suggesting to use `.constructor` everywhere.

**TL;DR:** In situations where `typeof` is not an option, and ***when you know that you do not care about the prototype chain***, [`Object.prototype.constructor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor) can be a viable or even better alternative than `instanceof`:

```
x instanceof Y
x.constructor === Y
```

It's been in the standard since 1.1, so no worries about backwards compatibility.

Muhammad Umer briefly mentioned this in a comment somewhere here too. It works on everything with a prototype - so everything not `null` or `undefined`:

```
// (null).constructor;      // TypeError: null has no properties
// (undefined).constructor; // TypeError: undefined has no properties

(1).constructor;                 // function Number
''.constructor;                  // function String
([]).constructor;                // function Array
(new Uint8Array(0)).constructor; // function Uint8Array
false.constructor;               // function Boolean()
true.constructor;                // function Boolean()

(Symbol('foo')).constructor;     // function Symbol()
// Symbols work, just remember that this is not an actual constructor:
// new Symbol('foo'); //TypeError: Symbol is not a constructor

Array.prototype === window.frames.Array;               // false
Array.constructor === window.frames.Array.constructor; // true
```

Furthermore, depending on your use case it can be *a lot* faster than `instanceof` (the reason likely being that it doesn't have to check the entire prototype chain). In my case I needed a fast way to check if a value is a typed array:

```
function isTypedArrayConstructor(obj) {
  switch (obj && obj.constructor){
    case Uint8Array:
    case Float32Array:
    case Uint16Array:
    case Uint32Array:
    case Int32Array:
    case Float64Array:
    case Int8Array:
    case Uint8ClampedArray:
    case Int16Array:
      return true;
    default:
      return false;
  }
}

function isTypedArrayInstanceOf(obj) {
  return obj instanceof Uint8Array ||
    obj instanceof Float32Array ||
    obj instanceof Uint16Array ||
    obj instanceof Uint32Array ||
    obj instanceof Int32Array ||
    obj instanceof Float64Array ||
    obj instanceof Int8Array ||
    obj instanceof Uint8ClampedArray ||
    obj instanceof Int16Array;
}
```

https://run.perf.zone/view/isTypedArray-constructor-vs-instanceof-1519140393812

And the results:

**Chrome 64.0.3282.167 (64-bit, Windows)**

[image: Typed Array instanceof vs constructor - 1.5x faster in Chrome 64.0.3282.167 (64-bit, Windows)]

**Firefox 59.0b10 (64-bit, Windows)**

[image: Typed Array instanceof vs constructor - 30x faster in Firefox 59.0b10 (64-bit, Windows)]

Out of curiousity, I did a quick toy benchmark against `typeof`; surprisingly it doesn't perform much worse, and it seems even a bit faster in Chrome:

```
let s = 0,
    n = 0;

function typeofSwitch(t) {
    switch (typeof t) {
        case "string":
            return ++s;
        case "number":
            return ++n;
        default:
            return 0;
    }
}

// note: no test for null or undefined here
function constructorSwitch(t) {
    switch (t.constructor) {
        case String:
            return ++s;
        case Number:
            return ++n;
        default:
            return 0;
    }
}

let vals = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
    vals.push(Math.random() <= 0.5 ? 0 : 'A');
}
```

https://run.perf.zone/view/typeof-vs-constructor-string-or-number-1519142623570

**NOTE: Order in which functions are listed switches between images!**

**Chrome 64.0.3282.167 (64-bit, Windows)**

[image: String/Number typeof vs constructor - 1.26x faster in Chrome 64.0.3282.167 (64-bit, Windows)]

**Firefox 59.0b10 (64-bit, Windows)**

**NOTE: Order in which functions are listed switches between images!**

[image: String/Number typeof vs constructor - 0.78x slower in Firefox 59.0b10 (64-bit, Windows)]

Answer (score 3):

no need to overwhelm with ton of above examples, just keep in mind two points of view:

1. `typeof var;` is an unary operator will return the original type or root type of var. so that it will return primitive types(`string`, `number`, `bigint`, `boolean`, `undefined`, and `symbol`) or `object` type.
2. in case of higher-level object, like built-in objects (String, Number, Boolean, Array..) or  complex or custom objects, all of them is `object` root type, but  instance type built base on them is vary(like OOP class inheritance concept), here `a instanceof A` - a binary operator - will help you, it will go through the prototype chain to check whether constructor of the right operand(A) appears or not.

so whenever you want to check "root type" or work with primitive variable - use "typeof", otherwise using "instanceof".

`null` is a special case,which is seemingly primitive, but indeed is a special case for object. Using `a === null` to check null instead.

on the other hand, `function` is also a special case, which is built-in object but `typeof` return `function`

as you can see `instanceof` must go through the prototype chain meanwhile `typeof` just check the root type one time so it's easy to understand why `typeof` is faster than `instanceof`

Answer (score 2):

Use instanceof because if you change the name of the class you will get a compiler error.

Answer (score 2):

Significant practical difference:

```
var str = 'hello word';

str instanceof String   // false

typeof str === 'string' // true
```

Don't ask me why.

Comment: Because here `str` is a string primitive, not a string object.  The same goes for number primitives and boolean primitives, they aren't instances of their "constructed" counterparts, the String, Number and Boolean objects.  JavaScript automatically converts these three primitives to objects when required (such as utilizing a method on the object's prototype chain).  On the flip side of your practical difference, *instanceof* is better for checking for arrays since `typeof [] == "object" // true`.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var newObj =  new Object;//instance of Object
var newProp = "I'm xgqfrms!" //define property
var newFunc = function(name){//define function 
 var hello ="hello, "+ name +"!";
 return hello;
}
newObj.info = newProp;// add property
newObj.func = newFunc;// add function

console.log(newObj.info);// call function
// I'm xgqfrms!
console.log(newObj.func("ET"));// call function
// hello, ET!

console.log(newObj instanceof Object);
//true
console.log(typeof(newObj));
//"object"
```

Comment: What should I do, can I get UA(navigator.userAgent)?

Answer (score 1):

According to [MDN documentation about typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof), objects instantiated with the "new" keyword are of type 'object':

```
typeof 'bla' === 'string';

// The following are confusing, dangerous, and wasteful. Avoid them.
typeof new Boolean(true) === 'object'; 
typeof new Number(1) === 'object'; 
typeof new String('abc') === 'object';
```

While [documentation about instanceof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) points that:

```
const objectString = new String('String created with constructor');
objectString instanceOf String; // returns true
objectString instanceOf Object; // returns true
```

So if one wants to check e.g. that something is a string no matter how it was created, safest approach would be to use `instanceof`.

Answer (score 1):

```js
/**
 * Did you ever heard of Anakandavada, the doctrine of manifoldness of reality?
 * 1) Check: typeof value === 'object'
 * 2) Check: value instanceof Object
 * 3) Check (1) *and* (2)
 * 4) neither
 * You may ponder to either use (1) or (2), but only (3) is right, because:
 * 1) Fails for functions, every function is also an object: Math.sqrt.test = "Hai"
 * 2) Fails for prototype-less objects: Object.create(null) instanceof Object === false.
 * @param {*} value - The actual value that we need to validate.
 * @returns {boolean} Boolean indicating if value is an object.
 */
function isObject(value) {
  return value instanceof Object || typeof value === 'object';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To be very precise 
**instanceof** should be used where value is created via the constructor (generally custom types) for e.g.

```
var d = new String("abc")
```

whereas **typeof** to check values created just by assignments for e.g

```
var d = "abc"
```

Answer (score -1):

Coming from a strict OO upbringing I'd go for

```
callback instanceof Function
```

Strings are prone to either my awful spelling or other typos. Plus I feel it reads better.

Answer (score -1):

Despite **instanceof** may be a little bit faster then **typeof**, I prefer second one because of such a possible magic:

```
function Class() {};
Class.prototype = Function;

var funcWannaBe = new Class;

console.log(funcWannaBe instanceof Function); //true
console.log(typeof funcWannaBe === "function"); //false
funcWannaBe(); //Uncaught TypeError: funcWannaBe is not a function
```

Answer (score -1):

One more case is that You only can collate with `instanceof` - it returns true or false. With `typeof` you can get type of provided *something*

Answer (score -1):

with performance in mind, you'd better use typeof
with a typical hardware, if you create a script with a loop of 10 million iterations
the instruction: typeof str == 'string' will take 9ms
while 'string' instanceof String will take 19ms

Answer (score -1):

***Of course it matters........ !***

Let's walk this through with examples.In our example we will declare function in two different ways.

We will be using both ***`function declaration`*** and  ***[Function Constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function)***. We will se how **`typeof`** and **`instanceof`** behaves in those two different scenarios.

***Create function using function declaration :***

```
function MyFunc(){  }

typeof Myfunc == 'function' // true

MyFunc instanceof Function // false
```

Possible explanation for such different result is, as we made a function declaration , **`typeof`** can understand that it is a function.Because **`typeof`** checks whether or not the expression on which typeof is operation on, in our case **`MyFunc`** **implemented *[Call Method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)* or  not**. If it implements **`Call`** method it is a function.Otherwise not .For clarification check ***[ecmascript specification for typeof](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.3)***.

***Create function using function constructor :***

```
var MyFunc2 = new Function('a','b','return a+b') // A function constructor is used 

typeof MyFunc2 == 'function' // true

MyFunc2 instanceof Function // true
```

Here **`typeof`** asserts that **`MyFunc2`** is a function as well as the **`instanceof`** operator.We already know **`typeof`** check if **`MyFunc2`** implemented **`Call`** method or not.As **`MyFunc2`** is a function and it implements **`call`** method,that's how **`typeof`** knows that it's a function.On the other hand, we used **`function constructor`** to create **`MyFunc2`**, it becomes an instance of **`Function constructor`**.That's why **`instanceof`** also resolves to **`true`**.

***What's safer to use ?***

As we can see in both cases **`typeof`** operator can successfully asserted that we are dealing with a function here,it is safer than **`instanceof`**. **`instanceof`** will fail in case of **`function declaration`** because **`function declarations`** are not an instance of **`Function constructor`**.

***Best practice :***

As ***[Gary Rafferty](http://garyrafferty.com/2012/12/07/JavaScript-instanceof-vs-typeof.html)***  suggested, the best way should be using both typeof and instanceof together.

```
  function isFunction(functionItem) {

        return typeof(functionItem) == 'function' || functionItem instanceof Function;

  }

  isFunction(MyFunc) // invoke it by passing our test function as parameter
```

Comment: any constructive criticism regarding this answer will be appreciated.