# Is there a way to look inside a (anonymous) function?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, anonymous-function

In JavaScript, let's say you have:

```
function doSomething(callback) {
    if (callback instanceof Function) callback();
}

doSomething(function() {
    alert('hello world');
});
```

Is there a way to check what is inside 'callback' (like, the fact that `alert()` is called) from `doSomething()`? Something like:

```
function doSomething(callback) {
    alert(callback.innards().indexOf('alert('));
}
```

I'm just curious

Comment: Why would you want to do such a thing?

Comment: Good discussion of typeof vs. instanceof here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/899574/which-is-best-to-use-typeof-or-instanceof

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Function.prototype.toString()](http://es5.github.com/#x15.3.4.2) gives an `implementation-dependent representation of the function`. However built-in functions will return something like:

```
function Array() {
   /* [native code] */
}
```

and host methods can return anything, even throw an error. So the strict answer is yes, maybe. But in a practical sense, it is not reliable.

Answer (score 1):

Some browsers support [toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/toString) on functions.

```
function doSomething(callback) {
    console.log( callback.toString().indexOf('alert(') )
    if (callback instanceof Function) callback();
}
```

Comment: `Some browsers`? It's in [ECMA-262](http://es5.github.com/#x15.3.4.2) so I would expect all browsers to support it. Do you know of any browser that doesn't?

Comment: @Saxoier duh, it is a text match. It is not going to be accurate. And you missed `var foo = "alert()";`

Comment: And i 'missed' `alert     (` and 1000 other possibilities.

Comment: @RobG should be good for all modern day browsers, brain does not remember if IE6 supports it and I am not going to whip open a VM to test it.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to say:

```
alert( callback.toString().indexOf('alert(') );
```

However that won't distinguish between the beginning of a function `alert(`, the beginning of a function `myspecialalert(`, and the text `"alert("` if it happens to be in a string literal - so you may need to do a bit of parsing.

Not sure how cross-browser this is, but in Firefox at least `.toString()` returns the whole text of the function including the word "function" and the parameter list.

Answer (score 0):

```
callback.toString().indexOf('alert(');
```

OR do a regex match like:

```
/alert *\(/.test(callback.toString());
```