# why mongodb typeof always returns "object"

Tags: mongodb, typeof

the following experiment is finished in a mongodb shell(I could not insert picture)

```
> db.test.remove()

> db.test.insert({"_id":1, "num":NumberLong(3)})

> db.test.find()

{ "_id" : 1, "num" : NumberLong(3) }

> typeof db.test.num

object

>
```

I wonder why the "typeof" always returns "object" type?

Comment: because it is an object? Also why are you testing db.test.num?

Comment: because I want to check which data structure mongo use to store my data. You know, if I do not use NumberLong(3), only use 3, mongodb will store the number using double type.

Comment: You will want to save your doc to a var first and test that vars properties

Comment: how to save one doc to a var? sorry I 'm a fresh man...

Comment: Wait do you wanna query for what datatype it is after saving or just make sure that the document you entered in console has the right type?

Comment: I wanna query for what datatype it is after saving

Comment: You prolly wanna do a find one as shown in Pete's answer

Comment: I tried Pete's answer, but it still not work, the a.num 's type is still "object". I think it should be 32bit integer, you know, the type number should be 16.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/shell-types/ everything in the shell is of type `object`.  If you want to check if a field is a certain type, you need to use `instanceof` which will return a `bool`.

To check the type of a field, and actually get the type.  Try the following (tested on 2.4.9):

```
a = db.foo.findOne();
typeof a.bar
```

That returns `number`.

EX:

[image]

It should be noted, that this is the type in JS, not necessarily the database.

Comment: Note that text does only apply to actual objects within documents and such, technically db.test.num should be undefined or null since it doesn't exist however that is not the case in reality

Comment: do you know how to check which data structure mongo use to store my data. You know, if I do not use NumberLong(3), only use 3, mongodb will store the number using double type.

Comment: It should be noted that typeof and instanceof are pretty much the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/899574/which-is-best-to-use-typeof-or-instanceof

Comment: @Sammaye they are essentially the same, except `typeof` returns a string, whereas `instanceof` is an actual comparison operator of the types.

Comment: but I try your example in my mongo shell, it seems something still goes wrong: `> a = db.test.findOne() 
{ "_id" : 1, "num" : NumberLong(3) }
> typeof a.num 
object 
>`

Comment: NumberLong isn't a javascript type. Its a BSON type.  "By default, the mongo shell treats all numbers as floating-point values."  When the value is deserialized for the shell, it is displayed in Constructor Notation, which is an `Object`, not a `Type`, as far as the shell is concerned.