# Identifying HTML documents in my object - javascript

Tags: javascript, function, object, methods, properties

In an effort to roll off my own object copier for javascript, I want to be able to identify what types each property has. This is my code:

```
function HandlerFunction(){
}

function item(){
    this.any=1;
    this.doc=document.createElement('DIV');
    this.onclick=new Function('HandlerFunction()');
}

var o={};
o=new item();
o.any.??? = a number indicating 'any' is a custom object name
o.doc.??? = a number indicating doc is an html object name
o.onclick.??? = a number indicating onclick is an even handler name
```

Is there a function I can use that can replace the question marks that allows me to separate the event handlers, the html elements and custom object names apart from each other so that I don't end up doing recursive copying when iterating through the properties in my future copy function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [instanceof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) for objects and [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) for primitives

```
o.doc instanceof HTMLElement // true
typeof o.any == "number" // true
o.onclick instanceof Function // true
typeof o.onclick == "function" // true, function also works with typeof
```

See [Which is best to use: typeof or instanceof?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899574/which-is-best-to-use-typeof-or-instanceof)

Comment: I'll look into these functions more.