# javascript object traversal with method property

Tags: javascript, object

How do you loop through a javascript object and if the object property you want happens to be a function, execute that function?

For example, the below code loops through an object and outputs its property based on some input. In the example `command.first` outputs fine, but when trying to output `command.clear` it returns the actual function as a string. 
Output: `"function(){ document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "";"`

```
var command = new Object();

command.first = "First string";

command.clear = function() { 
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "someStuff"; 
};

for(var key in command) {

    if(key == input) {

        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = command[input];

    }

}
```

Comment: You need `()` to execute a function. Either that or doing something like `.call()`

Comment: It outputs a function because it is a function. What is your question?

Comment: Check to see if it function and then do your code . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999998/how-can-i-check-if-a-javascript-variable-is-function-type

Comment: Btw, for this very code you don't need a loop at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to set innerHTML of a function that does not return anything and still you have to include '()' for your function for it to be executed.
Use this way

```
var command = new Object();
command.first = "First string";
command.clear = function() {     
document.getElementById( "output").innerHTML= "someStuff";
};
for ( var key in command) {
if (key == input) {
if(typeof(command[input])=="function"){
command[input]()
  }
else{
document.getElementById( "output" ).innerHTML= command[input]
 }
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if a certain value is instance of `Function` object. Any function (including arrow functions) is always an instance of `Function`:

```
var command = new Object();

command.first = "First string";
command.clear = function() { 
    return "someStuff"; 
};

for(var key in command) {
    if(key == input) {
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = command[input] instanceof Function ? command[input]() : command[input];
    }
}
```

You can see that `clear` doesn't change the `innerHTML` attribute of element directly. It just returns a string, and this string is assigned as value of `innerHTML` property inside the `for` loop.

Comment: I find it even easier to use `x typeof === "function"` instead of checking the prototype chain.

Comment: Why not use strict comparison ?

Comment: There's [an answer about that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6625960/1287643), and although I don't see any difference in this particular case, looks like you're right and generally it's better to check if a certain reference is a function using `typeof`.

Comment: So how to use typeof here? `if(typeof command[input] === "function) {document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = command[input]();}` This outputs `undefined`.

Comment: Because your function `command.clear` doesn't return anything, therefore it returns `undefined`.

Comment: I updated the answer: `clean` has to return a string, not change `innerHTML` attribute directly.