# How to properly find out type in javascript?

Tags: javascript, types, constructor

In this code sample:

*level.js*:

```
class Level {
  setLevel(level) {
    // if (typeof level === "number") {
    if (level.constructor === Number) {
      this._level = level;
    }
  }

  getLevel() {
    return this._level;
  }
}

module.exports = Level;
```

*index.js*:

```
const Level = require("./level");

let l = new Level();
l.setLevel(3);
console.log(l.getLevel());
```

I have 2 options of getting the type of input variable `level`: `typeof` or `[var].constructor`. Since JS is prototipical language, it seems more straightforward for me to use the one with constructor. Since every variable has one a it determines its real type. So why does everyone uses `typeof` and then compares its string result? (and hence are limit to only primitive types, whereas the constructor could be use witch custom/class variables)

Comment: "So why does everyone uses typeof" who is everyone? For checking class `instanceof` is usually used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `.constructor` is mutable
   See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39802529/19119805
2. `instanceof` also checks for "inherited" constructors
   See: [Difference between instanceof and constructor property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18172902/difference-between-instanceof-and-constructor-property)