# Check if passed parameter is Backbone.js view or command

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Check if passed parameter is Backbone.js view or command.

I'm passing a Backbone view into another as a parameter.

I need to test whether the passed function is a View and not a function of another type like a command for example.

What I came up with so far is something like this:

```
//content is the passed function
if (typeof content === 'function') {
        //do foo
}
```

This condition is true when you pass a function, which is true for both, commands and views.

So I need something like this:

```
if(view) {
    //do foo
} else if(command) {
    //do bar
}
```

Are there any unique attributes to Backbone views which I could check against?

Thank you!

Comment: maybe you can solve it by using the "instanceof" comparator as :   if (x instanceof Backbone.View) {
    ...
  }  else if (...) . for more information on istanceof you can check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7313559/what-is-the-instanceof-operator-used-for

Comment: @kawashita86 while you are right, you linked to a question on Java, and this questio is about JavaScript.

Comment: @EmileBergeron whoops, my bad. From a fast read of the answer the logic behind was so similar that I didn't double check which language the code was. Thank you for poiting that out. :)

Answer (score 2):

As [mentionned by kawashita86](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41260548/check-if-passed-parameter-is-backbone-js-view-or-command#comment69722125_41260548), you can use `instanceof` to test whether a function is of a specific type somewhere up the prototype chain.

```js
var MyViewType = Backbone.View.extend({}),
    myView = new MyViewType();


console.log("myView instanceof Backbone.View:", myView instanceof Backbone.View);

var MyOtherViewType = MyViewType.extend({}),
    myOtherView = new MyOtherViewType();

console.log("myOtherView instanceof Backbone.View:", myOtherView instanceof Backbone.View);
console.log("myOtherView instanceof MyViewType:", myOtherView instanceof MyViewType);
console.log("myOtherView instanceof MyOtherViewType:", myOtherView instanceof MyOtherViewType);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.3.3/backbone-min.js"></script>
```

More information:

- [What is the `instanceof` operator in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2449254/1218980)
- [Which is best to use: `typeof` or `instanceof`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/899574/1218980)