# Performance: typeof vs instanceof

Tags: javascript, performance, instanceof, typeof

I was wondering which one of `typeof` and `instanceof` is more performant, so I threw together the following little thing:

```js
let TIMES = 1000 * 1000 * 100

console.time("(() => { }) instanceof Function")
for (let i = 0; i < TIMES; i++)
  (() => { }) instanceof Function
console.timeEnd("(() => { }) instanceof Function")

console.time("(async () => { }) instanceof Function")
for (let i = 0; i < TIMES; i++)
  (async () => { }) instanceof Function
console.timeEnd("(async () => { }) instanceof Function")

console.time("(function () { }) instanceof Function")
for (let i = 0; i < TIMES; i++)
  (function () { }) instanceof Function
console.timeEnd("(function () { }) instanceof Function")

console.time("(async function () { }) instanceof Function")
for (let i = 0; i < TIMES; i++)
  (async function () { }) instanceof Function
console.timeEnd("(async function () { }) instanceof Function")

console.time("typeof (() => { }) === 'function'")
for (let i = 0; i < TIMES; i++)
  typeof (() => { }) === 'function'
console.timeEnd("typeof (() => { }) === 'function'")

console.time("typeof (async () => { }) === 'function'")
for (let i = 0; i < TIMES; i++)
  typeof (async () => { }) === 'function'
console.timeEnd("typeof (async () => { }) === 'function'")

console.time("typeof (function () { }) === 'function'")
for (let i = 0; i < TIMES; i++)
  typeof (function () { }) === 'function'
console.timeEnd("typeof (function () { }) === 'function'")

console.time("typeof (async function () { }) === 'function'")
for (let i = 0; i < TIMES; i++)
  typeof (async function () { }) === 'function'
console.timeEnd("typeof (async function () { }) === 'function'")
```

And got these super cool results from Chrome 66's console:

```
(() => { }) instanceof Function: 1789.844970703125ms
(async () => { }) instanceof Function: 2229.64208984375ms
(function () { }) instanceof Function: 1954.09716796875ms
(async function () { }) instanceof Function: 2279.995849609375ms
typeof (() => { }) === 'function': 412.8701171875ms
typeof (async () => { }) === 'function': 413.337890625ms
typeof (function () { }) === 'function': 413.387939453125ms
typeof (async function () { }) === 'function': 412.910888671875ms
```

Firefox 59 took forever to run that XD

I didn't have enough patience to wait for it and made TIMES ten times less:

```js
let TIMES = 1000 * 1000 * 10
```

With that I got the following out of Firefox 59's console:

```
(() => { }) instanceof Function: 5490ms
(async () => { }) instanceof Function: 6884ms
(function () { }) instanceof Function: 5408ms
(async function () { }) instanceof Function: 6938ms
typeof (() => { }) === 'function': 1916ms
typeof (async () => { }) === 'function': 1998ms
typeof (function () { }) === 'function': 1976ms
typeof (async function () { }) === 'function': 1972ms
```

Both result sets show that `typeof` is much faster than `instanceof`, the fact a couple of other people also mentioned in [Which is best to use: typeof or instanceof?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899574/which-is-best-to-use-typeof-or-instanceof).

My question is "y tho"?

Comment: But both are not interchangeable. The usecases of both the operators vary in certain cases. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899574/which-is-best-to-use-typeof-or-instanceof).

Comment: `typeof` checks only the type (one simple check), `instanceof` check also if it belongs to a super class (multiple checks)

Comment: My guess is because variables in the VM have a type token associated with them by default, which is quicker to check than pointer-chasing up to the prototype chain.

Comment: [The real problem is that programmers have spent far too much time worrying about efficiency in the wrong places and at the wrong times; premature optimization is the root of all evil (or at least most of it) in programming.](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth)

Answer (score 2):

As you also predicted and showed other links from SO, `typeof` will be faster (jsperf : https://jsperf.com/instanceof-vs-typeof/5), and this makes sense because `typeof` will return one of the built in types (**Object, undefined and the primitives**) while you get to control the right side of the `instanceof` operand. This means that the `instanceof` operator should check the **prototype chain** and see if the *right side* has been used as a **constructor** somewhere along. This is naturally more work.

Comment: In this case `(() => {}).__proto__` is directly `Function.prototype` so this is "just one check"

Comment: For an arrow function yes. Considering __proto__ is akin to `Object.getPrototypeOf`, seems like still, typeof is faster behind the scenes and whatever is done, cheaper than object property access.

Comment: This is just the general reminder about using one liner performance tests without paying a great deal of attention to details (optimizations being the dominant factor, cpu clock accuracy, ...) - [nice performance](https://i.imgur.com/i3Dh1u1.png). This is the reason why i downvote 95%+ of "performance tests" on stackoverflow that blindly draw conclusions from botched tests. I am not saying the result is wrong, just the weird jsperf tests should not be the fundament of the argumentation.

Comment: No it should not, I agree with it. There is tons of bottlenecks to optimize till it comes down to a versus between unpolyfillable in-built specs. I do not also think this can be compared fairly because the two operands are not the same at all.