# Get the format of the fields in a Typescript class

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs

I am implementing an application with Typescript and I have created a class with the following **fields:**

```
export class Car {
   name: string;
   model: string;
   year: number;
   saleDate: Date;
   seller: User;
}
```

Now I create an instance of that class in this way:

```
var myCar = new Car();
```

Can I go through the fields of the class and get the format of each one? It would be something like this (but it does not work):

```
for(var field in myCar) {
   console.log(typeof field);
}
// console result (it does not work):
// string
// string
// number
// Date
// User
```

This case actually always returns `'string'`. It makes sense, the key is really the name of the field, not the field itself.

Greetings.

Comment: `field` is the **name** of the property. To get the actual property, use `myCar[field]`. Or use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) or [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries).

Comment: [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof#Description) does not really work with non-primitives, all objects just come out as `object`. You can try out [instanceof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) Helpful SO [post about instanceof](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6625960/2033671)