# Proper way to do a try/except with catchall in javascript

Tags: javascript

What would be the correct way to do the following:

```
try {
    card.focus();
} catch(ReferenceError e) {
    console.log(e)
} catch (e) {
    console.log('damn')
}
```

In python it would be:

```
try:
    card.focus()
except ReferenceError as e:
    print e
except:
    print 'damn'
```

Comment: Non-standard, but https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the keyword [`instanceOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error#Handling_a_specific_errorSection) in order to check the Error type.

```js
try {
  card.focus();
} catch (error) {
  if (error instanceof ReferenceError) console.log("Not defined!");
}
```

Comment: thanks for this -- why are the `{...}` not required on the console.log statement? I've never seen a statement inside an `if` be written without brackets?

Comment: @DavidL `{...}` are optional if and only if there's exactly one statement to be controlled by the `if` conditional.

Comment: @DavidL The short answer is that javascript syntax is pretty laid back and you don't really need them here unless you want multiple statements. But even that isn't necessarily required thanks to the comma operator.

Comment: @DavidL read this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797286/are-curly-braces-necessary-in-one-line-statements-in-javascript)

Comment: Noting that there are [issues with *instanceOf*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35081067/257182), also see [*this answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18057157/257182).

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that, unfortunately. Closest thing is to do it in the `catch` block.

```
try {
  // something
} catch (e) {
  if (e.errorCode === 400) {
     // something
  } else if (e.errorCode === 404) {
     // something
  } ...
}
```

Comment: what are the different error codes that correspond to "ReferenceError", etc.? Or is there a place to find those?

Comment: ah, no, this was to highlight the logic of doing it in the catch block. for exact error types you should use `typeOf`; the list of default javascript exceptions is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error#Error_types.

Comment: Important to note that you can also _create your own errors_, and those might have other properties you want to check.

Answer (score 1):

The feature you're looking for is not part of any JavaScript standard, but was at one point available in certain browsers. It is not available in current browsers, however.

Instead, [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) suggest having a single `catch` block, within which you can test the type of the error and drive your desired behavior accordingly. So, something like:

```
try {
    card.focus();
} catch (e) {
    if (e instanceof ReferenceError) {
       // statements to handle ReferenceError exceptions
    } else {
       // statements to handle any unspecified exceptions
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a class the catches error is an instance of you can use `instanceof`:

```
try {
   card.focus();
} catch(error) {
  if(error instanceof ReferenceError)console.log(error);
  else alert("Something went wrong! "  + error);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the *instanceof* operator is not recommended as it fails across frames and windows as the *constructor.prototype* in the origin context is different to the one in the testing context (and different objects are never `==` or `===`).

There are other options.

You can get the error object's class, but that typically just returns "[object Error]":

```
Object.prototype.toString.call(new ReferenceError()); // [object Error]
```

However, you can also use the [*name*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-nativeerror.prototype.name) property which is set to the name of the constructor, so:

```
new ReferenceError().name; // ReferenceError
```

is more reliable than *instanceof*. E.g.:

```js
try {
  undefinedFunction();
} catch (e) {
  if (e.name == 'ReferenceError') {
    console.log(`Ooops, got a ${e.name}. :-)`);
  } else {
    console.log(`Ooops, other error: ${e.name}. :-(`);        
  }
}
```