# How is typeof string not an instanceof String?

Tags: javascript, node.js

In the following code, if `typeof` of `something` and `arbit` comes out to be `string`, why doesn't `instanceof String` return `true`:

```
const roles = ['something', 'arbit'];
console.log("Array.isArray(roles):", Array.isArray(roles));
console.log("roles instanceof Array:", (roles instanceof Array));
roles.forEach(element => {
    console.log(`[${element}]`);
    console.log(`\ttypeof(${element}):`, typeof(element));
    console.log(`\t${element} instanceof String:`, (element instanceof String));
});
```

The output for this is:

```
Array.isArray(roles): true
roles instanceof Array: true
[something]
        typeof(something): string
        something instanceof String: false
[arbit]
        typeof(arbit): string
        arbit instanceof String: false
```

Also, `roles instanceof Array` evaluates to `true`. Thoroughly confused.

This is plain JavaScript running in Nodejs 12, though I doubt that makes any difference...

Comment: This might be helpful, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899574/what-is-the-difference-between-typeof-and-instanceof-and-when-should-one-be-used

Comment: @FoggyDay What does this have to do with Typescript, I'm using pure JavaScript. Did I miss something?

Comment: @JazzBrotha That was helpful, thanks!

Comment: Helpful, but the real issue is "String" vs. "string".  See [Evert's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59980364/3135317) reply and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14727044/typescript-difference-between-string-and-string) thread.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript has two main ways to make strings, as a literal:

```
const foo = "hi";
```

and via the string constructor

```
const bar = new String("hi");
```

These are not the same thing. The second one will be a bit slower and have subtle behavior differences.

So the reason `instanceof String` doesn't work, is because your literal string is not an instance of this class.

Generally you'll want to avoid `new String()`.

Comment: This is the correct answer.  It's also discussed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14727044/typescript-difference-between-string-and-string) thread.

Answer (score 2):

Use typeof element === "string" instead of instanceof.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof
instanceof doesn't work with primitive data types.