# Generic Union type, Value or Function in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

How to safely get the value from generic type `V | ((k: K) => V)`?

It's a common case to provide default value as a value or as result of a function.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEASkAsA8BpANNAagPmgbwChpoBzAUwBcB9AewCcqATMgMzAFcQKAKAawC5o6aIxZdBmaAB9o3PoJQBKaAF5cmRYon4ixaHUrs6AO1kUAngAcyNFiLEVVK6AHIW7Y8AoBLGsZfQAPz2XHzKgqJcugC+BNFAA)

```
class Hash<K, V> {
  get_or_default(k: K, dflt: V | ((k: K) => V)): V {
    return (typeof dflt == 'function' ? dflt(k) : dflt
  }
}
```

The problem is this `dflt(k)` it refuses to compile because it:

```
This expression is not callable.
  Not all constituents of type '((k: K) => V) | (V & Function)' are callable.
    Type 'V & Function' has no call signatures.(2349)
```

P.S. Why `dflt: Exclude<V, Function> | ((k: K) => V)` doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `instanceof` instead of `typeof`.

```
class Hash<K, V> {
  get_or_default(k: K, dflt: V | ((k: K) => V)): V {
    return (dflt instanceof Function) ? dflt(k) : dflt;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, strange, isn't it the same as typeof?

Comment: `instanceof` should be used with custom types, and `typeof` with primitives, shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899574/what-is-the-difference-between-typeof-and-instanceof-and-when-should-one-be-used)